# Reset action url of firebase password reset

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

[image]I have customised the firebase `actionURL` related with password reset and email address verification but I want to revert that changes. How to reset it to default `actionURL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there's no reset action when you've only changed the action URL.

A quick workaround is to make a change to the actual template itself. After doing that, you'll get a large reset banner at the top of the template:

[image]

**Update**: the above steps reset the template, but not the action URL. You can manually reenter the original URL, which is `https://<your-project-name>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>`.

Comment: It looks like now you need to remove the querystring when entering in the original action URL. 

This worked for me: `https://<your-project-name>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action`